# In all of Southeast Asia" or "In Southeast Asia"

Tags: superlatives

I found a sentence from  a book "Travel in Singapore":

**Jurong Birdpark is the largest Bird Park in all of Southeast Asia.**

Can I put the phrase  "In all of southeast asia" at the beginning of sentence?

> 1. In all of Southeast Asia, the Jurong Bird Park is the largest park.
> 2. In Southeast Asia, the Jurong Bird Park is the largest
>      park.

I also want to know I need to add "all of" in the sentence of superlative degree.

Comment: You don't _have to_ use "all of", but you can. "All of" emphasizes that you are talking about the entirety of something.

Comment: @P.E. Dant Please explain how the second sentence differ from the first sentence in meaning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "All of" emphasizes that you are referring to every square inch of S.E. Asia. Thus, the first sentence is more emphatic than the second. If you are not familiar with the English verb _emphasize,_ please follow [**this link.**](http://www.onelook.com/?w=emphasize&ls=a) (It is unclear what you mean by this sentence: _"I also want to know I need to add 'all of' in the sentence of superlative degree."_)

Comment: This sentence mean "Is the second sentence natural?"

Comment: Both are "natural" in English, but the first is more expressive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can start your sentence with the said prepositional phrase.

The usage of "all of" in front of Southest Asia is also correct grammatically. It adds emphasis on the entirety of Southeast Asia, though it sounds a bit superfluous in the sentence. It'll be more idiomatic if you say "....the greatest park in Southeast Asia: "in Southeast Asia" also conveys the sense "in the entirety of Southeast Asia".